# "intercept" login & registration events in WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is there a way to "intercept" login or registration event in WSO2 Identity Server?
I know that wso2is architecture is quite complex, also there are some extension points, but I didn't find any information regarding how intercept those events.
I'd like to replicate something available in Gigya that allows to configure an API endpoint to call when one of those events happen (passing some information regarding the user)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a userstore listener to get this done. More details are available on wso2 official documentation.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/User+Store+Listeners

Comment: Thanks,
I'll dig into this solution